# Hibernate: many-to-many through additional table

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, entity-relationship, foreign-key-relationship

I have these tables, organization can be a sender or receiver of many messages, a msg can have 2 organizations that send it or receive. I know that my db doesnt make sense but i cant change it:

[image: enter imad description here]

So, do i connect SenderReceiver to Msg as 1-to-n, and Organization to SenderReceiver as n-to-1? or vice versa n-to1 and 1-to-n?

**Senderreceiver**:

```
public class Senderreceiver implements java.io.Serializable {

        private Set<Organization> organizations = new HashSet();
        private Set<Msg> msg = new HashSet();
```

*xml file*:

```
<set fetch="select" inverse="true" lazy="true" name="msgs" table="MSG">
      <key>
        <column name="MsgID" not-null="true"/>
      </key>
      <one-to-many class="entity3.Msg"/>
    </set>



<set fetch="select" inverse="true" lazy="true" name="organizations"  table="ORGANIZATION">
      <key>
        <column name="OrganizationID" not-null="true"/>
      </key>
      <one-to-many class="entity3.Organization"/>
    </set>
```

**Msg**:

```
public class Msg implements java.io.Serializable {

        private Senderreceiver senderreceiver;
```

*xml*:

```
<many-to-one class="entity3.Senderreceiver" fetch="select" name="senderreceiver">
      <column name="SenderReceiverID" not-null="true"/>
    </many-to-one>
```

**Organization**:

```
public class Organization implements java.io.Serializable {

        private Senderreceiver senderreceiver;
```

*xml*:

```
 <many-to-one class="entity3.Senderreceiver" fetch="select" name="senderreceiver">
          <column name="SenderReceiverID" not-null="true"/>
        </many-to-one>
```

Any help would be appreceited. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest this:

As I see it, this is 2-N relation. An organization can send many messages and a message can be sent or received only by one or two organization. You dont need a connection table.

put a set of messages in the organization - this will represent the messages sent/received by the organization. You can also make 2 sets - `sentMSGS` and `receivedMSGS`.

and put a FK of the organization in the message itself, as this will represnt the oganization of the message. You can put a `sentID` and `receviedID` in a message.

I think this will make the understanding of the table and the program more easy.

If you choose to stay with the original relations, a many to many relation will be presented as:

1-N-1 (`Organization-SenderReceiver-Msg`).

`Organization-SenderReceiver` is 1-N
and `SenderReceiver-Msg` is N-1.

So you put a collection of `SenderReceiver` in both the `Organization` and the `Msg` classes. And objects of both `Organization` and `Msg` inside the `SenderReceiver`.

Comment: Thank you for answer! you see, i cant change db at all. I was told that organization-msg are many-to-many. Does 1-N-1 reflects this?

Comment: Yes, make `organization-SenderReceiver` 1-N and `SenderReceiver-Msg` N-1.

Answer (score 1):

The SenderReceiver table has a foreign key to Organization, and a foreign key to Message. This is a clear sign that a SenderReceiver may only have one Message, and One organization.

You thus have

- a OneToMany between Organization and SenderReceiver,
- a ManyToOne between SenderReceiver and Organization,
- a OneToMany between Message and SenderReceiver
- a ManyToOne between SenderReceiver and Message

Whether you map all those associations is up to you. Each association may be unidirectional or bidirectional.

Comment: thanks for answer! Logically i need many-to-many  between Organization and Message. How do i map all those things?

Comment: No, you don't, because then you could not map the Role column in the SenderReceiver table.